# What tense to use when referencing "unknown past" from the future?

Tags: tenses

In class, we conducted an experiment where we filled dialysis tubing with sucrose solutions of unknown concentrations, then placed them in distilled water to let osmosis take place. In my analysis of the experiment, I wrote this:

> The dialysis tube with the highest percent change in mass after the experiment will have contained the most concentrated solution before the experiment.

At first, it seemed unnecessary to me to write "after the experiment" and "before the experiment," but I think that it is actually needed because the concentration of sucrose in the tube changed over the duration of the experiment.

I also think that "will have contained" sounds incorrect because it uses the future "will" and the past "contained," and I'm not sure which tense I should actually be using.

How can I make this sentence grammatically correct and easy to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing the change in mass is *part* of the experiment, so it's not something that is only observed one the experiment is over.

Also, you're drawing a conclusion and, therefore, stating what you believe to be a fact.

So:

> The dialysis tube with the highest percent change in mass ***during*** the experiment ***must*** have contained the most concentrated solution.